# [ SQL Error 15173 ]Unable to drop a SQL Server Login (Login is a AD Group)

Tags: sql-server, security

Recently I have added a SQL Server Login and later want to drop it.
But I am seeing below issue, can you please see what is my miss here.

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Login []    Script Date: 5-6-2022 15:11:42 ******/
DROP LOGIN [domain\group]
GO
```

> Msg 15173, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Server principal 'domain\group'
> has granted one or more permission(s). Revoke the permission(s) before
> dropping the server principal.

```
Select * 
  from sys.server_permissions 
 where grantor_principal_id = 
           (Select principal_id 
              from sys.server_principals 
              where name = N'domain\group');
```

[image]

I tried revoking the permission, but I am not successful.
Any help on this.

Comment: Try checking column `grantee_principal_id` instead of `grantor_principal_id` to identify the permissions granted.

Comment: Please check this thread - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/253237/how-do-i-force-the-delete-of-users-from-my-database/253242#253242

Comment: Thanks , it helps to an extent.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the below process to fix my issue.

```
SELECT class_desc,* FROM sys.server_permissions 
WHERE grantor_principal_id = (
SELECT principal_id FROM sys.server_principals WHERE NAME = N'domain\group')

SELECT NAME ,type_desc FROM sys.server_principals 
WHERE principal_id IN (
SELECT grantee_principal_id FROM sys.server_permissions
WHERE grantor_principal_id = (
SELECT principal_id FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE NAME = N'domain\group'))
```

[image]
[image]

Based on output, it means there is an Server_principal on which domain\group has been granted permission of VIEW DEFINITION. Second result shows that I have used my account i.e. domain\group to create SERVER_PRINCIPAL and granted permission to xxxxx account .

Now , I did below steps:

1. SQL Server --> Security
2. Server Roles --> Name (Output from the above second query)
3. General --> Logins
4. Identify the server_principal you are trying to delete
5. Uncheck all the permissions you assigned
6. Finally remove the login by below command.

   ```
   use [master]
   GO
   REVOKE VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::[domain\group] 
   TO [*Name_output_of_above_2nd query*] 
   AS [domain\group]
   GO
   DROP LOGIN [domain\group]
   GO
   ```